# Replacing last comma on each line

Tags: regular-expression, search, replace

The following will replace the first comma on each line with a pipe:

```
:%s/,/|/
```

How can I do the same for the last comma?

Answer (score 6):

The best way to do this is to allow any character except for a newline, `.` any number of times, `*` followed by a comma `,`. This gives us the following regex:

```
:%s/\(.*\),/\1|
```

Or, the more readable way:

```
:%s/\v(.*),/\1|
```

This works because `*` is [*"greedy"*](http://vimregex.com/#Non-Greedy) by default, meaning it will match as many characters as possible.

Comment: Clever! Why didn't I think of that. One more question: Sorry if this comes off as noobish, but why does this statement work without the final "/" in the replacement?

Comment: @JonathanEricsson No worries! We've all been a noob at one point. `:)` In general, the last slash is never necessary, unless you need to specify a flag, like `/g` or `/c`. You could even do just this: `:%s/,` and the will remove the first comma on every line.

Comment: This could be simplified to `:%s/.*\zs,/|`.

Answer (score 4):

Another one:

```
:s/,\ze[^,]\{-}$/|
```

Comment: Since you're using the lazy version, would `.\{-}` be enough?

Answer (score 3):

An alternative, just for the sake of it :)

```
%s/\v.*\zs,\ze[^,]*/|
```

This can be translated as: go search (`s`) on each line (`%`) for any number of chars (`.*`) followed by "a comma not followed by another one, i.e. followed by any other character, but comma" (`,[^,]*`). Using `\zs` and `\ze` around that one comma, we alter the match to only contain the character we want to act on. Therefore, the replacement part is simply the bar.

*Edit/Update*: of course, as [Karl Yngve Lervåg](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/21/karl-yngve-lerv%c3%a5g) mentions, the part after the comma isn't needed at all ..., so:

```
:%s/.*\zs,/|
```

... is the better incantation.

Comment: The part from `\ze` and on can be removed.

Comment: Hah, so obvious apres coup :)

Answer (score 3):

Oh, I'll jump on the bandwagon. I can't resist a good regular expression question. :)

Since really what we're trying to find is a "comma with no commas after it," i propose we use a negative lookahead.

```
:%s/,\(.*,\)\@!/|/g
```

This matches a comma only if it does not have `.*,` following it. However it only matches the comma since anything in a lookaround is only for context and not part of the match. Then we substitute it with a pipe, and our job is done.

Answer (score 1):

I will prefer to go with a macro.
Go to line 1 `:1`.
Press `qa` to start recording in  register `A`.
Then, type `$` to move to end of line. Then, `F,` or `/,<CR>N` to search backwards for a comma. Then, press `r|` to replace it with a bar. Press `j` to move to next line. Press `@a` to replay macro recursively. Then, stop macro by pressing `q`.
(In cade, if The macro runs infinitely at the last line of file. You can abort it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.)

Comment: Cool solution, but this won't work if the comma is the last character on the line, or if one of the lines doesn't have a comma.

Comment: I will check once and try to cover them too.